# Expectation values of $x$ and $p$ for particle in a box case

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, wavefunction, hilbert-space, superposition

My Internet search just told me how to find the expectation value of $x$ and $p$ for when the particle is in a box is in a particular eigenstate. However, how do we do the find the expectation values when the particle is in the superimposed state of $\sum_{n}c_{n}\psi _{n}$?

Also, as the $\psi _{n}$ are not a eigenfunction of  $x$ and $p$ operators, can we interpret the result as the weighted sum of individual expectation values for individual $\psi _{n}$?

Also can anyone tell what exactly is a stationary state?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming your $\psi_n$s are functions of $x$. The expectation value of any operator $A(x,p)$ is given by,
$$\langle A\rangle=\int dx\,\Psi^*(x)\,A\left(x,i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)\Psi(x)=\sum_m\sum_n (c^*_mc_{n})\int dx \,\psi^*_m\,A\left(x,i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\right)\psi_n$$
where,
$$\Psi(x)=\sum_n c_n\psi_n$$

If the $\psi_n$s are eigenfunctions of $A$, and form an ***orthonormal*** set, then the expression can be further simplified. Say,
$$A\psi_n=a_n\psi_n$$
Then we can write,
$$\langle A\rangle=\sum_m\sum_n(c^*_mc_{n})\,a_n\int dx\,\psi_m^*\psi_n=\sum_m\sum_n(c^*_mc_{n})\,a_n\,\delta_{mn}=\sum_n|c_n|^2a_n$$

For your second question, I am sure any standard textbook will have a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

In general
\begin{align}
\langle A\rangle & = \sum_{nm} c_n c_m^* \int dx\, e^{iE_mt/\hbar} \psi^*_m(x) \hat A \psi_n(x)e^{-iE_nt/\hbar}\, ,\\
&= \sum_{nm} c_n c_m^*  e^{i(E_m-E_n) t/\hbar}\int dx\, \psi^*_m(x) \hat A \psi_n(x)\, .
\end{align}
You cannot do better without knowing the form of $\hat A$.  Thus, if $\hat A=\hat x$ or $\hat A=\hat p$ for the infinite well, then
\begin{align}
\langle x(t)\rangle &= \frac{2}{L}\sum_{nm} c_n c_m^*  e^{iE_1(1/m^2-1/n^2) t/\hbar}\int_0^L 
dx\,x\cos\left(\frac{m\pi x}{L}\right)\cos\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)\, , \\
\langle p(t)\rangle &= \frac{2}{L}\sum_{nm} c_n c_m^*  e^{iE_1(1/m^2-1/n^2) t/\hbar}\int_0^L 
dx\,\cos\left(\frac{m\pi x}{L}\right)\left(-i\hbar\frac{d}{dx}\right)\cos\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)\, .
\tag{1}
\end{align}
This is not a weighted sum of average values because there can be cross-terms with $n\ne m$.

In *some* circumstances, you can easily figure out $\langle p(t)\rangle$.  Since $\hat p$ is an observable, its average value must be real for all $t$ so that.  Given the rhs of (1), this means 
$$
\frac{2}{L}\sum_{nm} c_n c_m^*  e^{iE_1(1/m^2-1/n^2) t/\hbar}\int_0^L  dx\,
\cos\left(\frac{m\pi x}{L}\right)\left(\hbar\frac{d}{dx}\right)\cos\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)\, .
$$
must be purely imaginary.  In general, this can only happen when
$\sum_{nm} c_n c_m^*  e^{iE_1(1/m^2-1/n^2) t/\hbar} $ is purely imaginary since the integral is necessarily real. In the special case where $t=0$ and all the $c$'s are real, this double sum cannot be purely imaginary meaning that $\langle p\rangle=0$ for this case.  Alternatively, if $\langle x\rangle$ is time-independent, then $\langle p\rangle=0$ since, by Ehrenfest’s theorem, $\langle p\rangle = m\frac{d}{dt}\langle x\rangle$.

A stationary state is an eigenstate of the Hamiltonian $H$.  It is also a solution to the time-independent Schrodinger equation.  In practice, since $\Psi_n(x,t)=\psi_n(x)e^{-iE_nt/\hbar}$, the stationary states have the property that the probability distribution $\vert \Psi(x,t)\vert ^2=\vert \psi(x)\vert^2$ is independent of $t$.